# Something about shared_ptr I don't get

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

When I run this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
struct Adaptee {
    int value = 0;
};

class Adapter {
    private:
        Adaptee* adaptee;
    public:
        Adapter (Adaptee* a) : adaptee(a) {}
        void increaseValueByOne() {adaptee->value++;}
};

int main() {
    Adaptee* a = new Adaptee;
    Adapter* adapter = new Adapter(a);
    adapter->increaseValueByOne();  
    delete adapter;
    std::cout << "a->value = " << a->value << std::endl;
}
```

I get the output: a->value = 1.  But when I run this:

```
struct Adaptee {
    int value = 0;
};

class Adapter {
    private:
        std::shared_ptr<Adaptee> adaptee;
    public:
        Adapter (Adaptee* a) : adaptee (std::shared_ptr<Adaptee>(a)) {}
        void increaseValueByOne() {adaptee->value++;}
};

int main() {
    Adaptee* a = new Adaptee;
    Adapter* adapter = new Adapter(a);
    adapter->increaseValueByOne();
    delete adapter;
    std::cout << "a->value = " << a->value << std::endl;
}
```

I get: a->value = 7738248

Why is this?  Isn't the use_count of adapter->adaptee simply changing from 2 to 1, so nothing should go wrong?  When I remove the line 'delete adapter;' everything is fine though, but then there is leaking.

Comment: Why don't you trace it line-by-line in the debugger? It's a great way to figure out why any piece of code runs the way it does.

Comment: you're kinda misusing allocation and shared pointers here.  If your main had `Adapter adapter{new Adaptee};` you wouldn't be able to get this odd behavior.

Comment: by using a shared pointer you are giving `Adapter` at least partial ownership of the `Adaptee` object.  When Adapter dies, it deallocated the object it points to.  When you mix shared pointers with `delete` you're on your own, that's not how the library is suppose to be used.

Comment: Why would the use count be 2? There's only one shared pointer, which dies with `delete adapter`.

Comment: @ Mike.  Yes, I realize that now.  I thought a owned it too when it wasn't even a shared_ptr.  Had I realized this before, this post never would have shown up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because in the second case `Adaptee` instance is deleted by the destructor of `shared_ptr` when you `delete adapter` as it's the last `shared_ptr` owning that object. See [the doc](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr).

If you want to keep the adaptee alive after you delete adapter, you should wrap it into shared_ptr from the start:

```
class Adapter {
    private:
        std::shared_ptr<Adaptee> adaptee;
    public:
        Adapter (const std::shared_ptr<Adaptee>& a) : adaptee (a) {}
        void increaseValueByOne() {adaptee->value++;}
};

int main() {
    std::shared_ptr<Adaptee> a(new Adaptee);
    Adapter* adapter = new Adapter(a);
    adapter->increaseValueByOne();
    delete adapter;
    std::cout << "a->value = " << a->value << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: I thought it is shared by a and adapter->adaptee, so the use_count was 2.  But let's say you are right, then the only way to delete adapter in this case, is to declare it as a smart pointer?

Comment: If you just want to output the correct `a->value` you can simply move the printing code before `delete adapter`.

Comment: @ Anton.  I want to keep a and its intended value of 1 after deleting adapter.

Comment: Then wrap adaptee in shared_ptr from the start. Check the updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

In the first case, the line

```
delete adapter;
```

did nothing to `adaptee`. It is still a valid pointer.

In the second case, the same line calls the destructor of the `shared_ptr`, which  deallocates the memory pointed to by `adaptee`. Hence, `adaptee` is not a valid pointer and you can expect undefined behavior if you dereference it.

Answer (score 1):

The principle of the `shared_ptr` is to manage the deletion of the pointed object when it's no longer used.

When you [create](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr/) the `shared_ptr`in your adapter, it takes ownership of the object and sets the use count to 1.  When the adapter is deleted, so is the shared pointer.  THe use count  (that you can display with [`use_count()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/shared_ptr/use_count/)) is hence automatically decremented and reaches zero.  So the object is deleted and a points to an invalid address.

If you dont' want the `shared_ptr` to release the memory of a when deleting `adapter`, you should create your original pointer as shared_pointer as well:

```
int main() {
    auto a = std::make_shared<Adaptee>();   //shared pointer instead of Adaptee* a = new Adaptee;
    ...
    }
```

And add an additional constructor in class Adapter:

```
Adapter(std::shared_ptr<Adaptee> a) : adaptee(a) {}
```

With this consistent use of `shared_ptr`,the use count of shared pointer would go to 1  when adapter is deleted, and the rest of your code will work as you exepect, printing 1 as in your original version.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on what others are saying, when you give a raw heap allocated pointer to a `shared_ptr`, you are giving the `shared_ptr` control over the lifetime of the resource. `shared_ptr` keeps a reference count of how many `shared_ptr`s are pointing to a resource. When that count is `0` the resource is cleaned up.

```
adaptee (std::shared_ptr<Adaptee>(a))
```

Here, the reference count is `1` because there is `1` `shared_ptr` pointing to the resource `a`.

```
delete adapter;
```

causes the `shared_ptr` in `adapter` to go out of scope. The `shared_ptr`'s destructor is called, which decrements the reference count. Since the reference count is now `0`, `delete` is called on `a`.

```
std::cout << "a->value = " << a->value << std::endl;
```

Here, a is no longer a valid pointer because `delete` was called in the destructor of the `shared_ptr`.

If you want `a` to stay valid you should do the following:

```
struct Adaptee {
    int value = 0;
};

class Adapter {
    private:
        std::shared_ptr<Adaptee> adaptee;
    public:
        Adapter (std::shared_ptr<Adaptee> a) : adaptee(a) {}
        void increaseValueByOne() {adaptee->value++;}
};

int main() {
    std::shared_prt<Adaptee> a = std::make_shared<Adaptee>(); //reference count is 1
    Adapter* adapter = new Adapter(a); //reference count is 2
    adapter->increaseValueByOne();
    delete adapter; //reference count is 1
    std::cout << "a->value = " << a->value << std::endl;
} // reference count is 0; memory is deallocated
```

Comment: Ok. Everything is perfectly clear to me now. I realize my fallacy: I thought in the original code, the use_count of adapter->adaptee was 2 (owned by itself and a), but a was not a shared_ptr so the use count was actually 1 (and then turned to 0 when adapter was deleted). I suppose to be consistent, adapter should be a shared_ptr as well (and don't bother calling delete on it at all).

Comment: Consider using `unique_ptr` instead of `shared_ptr` for `adapter`. Or just stack allocate it by doing `Adapter adapter(a); adapter.increaseValueByOne();`